# Android music player application

Tags: android

I have created a music player app. While playing music if the user comes back to the previous activity the music still keeps playing. How to solve it?

Comment: Are you playing music using service, if yes then you have stop service and  handle lifecycle of Media Player. Post your code for better understanding.

Comment: No I'm not using service, actually my app is like an audio book, it plays the content whenever read button is pressed. While playing if I press back then the audio still keeps playing

Comment: I think you have to stop playing music, in onBackPress..

Comment: Ok I'll check, thanks for your suggestions guys.

Comment: Do you want the music to stop when the user leaves the activity? Then you should implement the onPause handler in the activity. That handles every case where your activity goes out of focus.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416969/6017001

Answer (score 0):

Use the back press method and invoke the stop method of MediaPlayer

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.x);
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   player.stop();
}
```

Try this